# I want element to decrease in size based how much space does the element next to it take space on the screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

So I want the divider line on the picture to decrease or increase in size based on the All publications link. Currently I have done it like this, but I'm wondering if there's a better solution for this?

[image]

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {

    .dividing .col-xs-6 {
        width:75%;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {

    .dividing .col-xs-6 {
        width:65%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 423px) {

    .dividing .col-xs-6 {
        width:55%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal demo with demonstrating the issue?

Comment: In particluar some idea of the html structure would be useful.

Comment: There are several solutions for making a div expand/contract to fill remaining space...which one is most appropriate will depend on your HTML.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answers, I made a demo here http://www.bootply.com/ifNB6XyEDC. But I think I should get it working with a :before element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a :before element:

```css
h2{
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 2em;
    text-align: right;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: #34495e;
    padding-bottom: 1em;
}
h2:before{
    content: '';
    flex: 1 0 0;
    margin-right: 0.25em;
    height: 2px;
    background: #34495e;
}
```

```html
<h2><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Test</a></h2>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that!

Comment: How do you make the line be in the vertical center of the text?

Comment: Edited it just add a little `margin` to the bottom of the pseudo element

Comment: Came up with a better solution `align-items: center;` instead of `align-items: flex-end;`

Comment: Thanks! One more thing, is it possible to make only the text clickable not the line itself?